# Jquery slider UI issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having trouble with the min and max values of the jQuery Slider UI.  I set the min value to 5000 and the max value to 1000000 with 25000 step increments.  However when I view it on the front-end I get the following:

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      step:25000,
      min: 5000,
      max: 1000000,
      values: [ 5000, 1000000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#657401867-MinPrice" ).val( (ui.values[ 0 ] + "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
        //$( "#MinPrice" ).text( ui.values[ 0 ] );
        $( "#657401867-MaxPrice" ).val( (ui.values[ 1 ] + "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
        //$( "#MaxPrice" ).text( ui.values[ 1 ] ); ($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
      }
    });
```

So for some reason, on the front end it has the max value as 980,000 instead of 1,000,000.

Comment: This is because you start at `5,000`. The closest you can get to `1,000,000` from there at steps of `25,000` is `980,000`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/watckx6h/. In fact, I get the behavior where the second slider value becomes 1,005,000 when moving it around. What versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because the `step` value is `25,000`. If you increment your `min` of `5,000` by `25,000`, the largest possible value is `980,000`, since your `max` is `1,000,000`. I'd recommend changing the `step` value to `5,000` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 5,000 (your `min` value), in steps of 25,000 (`step` value), the highest step lower than 1,000,000 (your `max`) is actually 980,000.

In order to avoid this you should do on of these options:

- Change the `step` to be 5,000
- Set the `min` value to be 0 or 25,000
- Change `max` value to 1,005,000